# Question for pre-univerisity math

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to help a friend who's doing math from pre-university, and realised I have forgot everything from that time.

The question is following.

Points $M$ and $N$ are on the the equation $y=x^2-3x-2$.

Point $P=(7,8)$.

$M$ is right between $N$ and $P$. What are the coordinates of $M$ and $N$?

My initial thought was some kind of middle point formula, but that requires more knows points.

I know this should be an easy task, but I would appreciate any input on how to solve this!

Answer (score 2):

They are on the *locus* of the equation $y=x^2-3x-2$, or on the graph of the function $x\mapsto x^2-3x-2$ as understood in $\Bbb R$.

If $M=(a,b)$, $N=(c,d)$, we are told: $$\frac{c+7}{2}=a,\,\frac{d+8}{2}=b$$By the "right between" comment (standard midpoint formula).

I also know $b=a^2-3a-2$ and $d=c^2-3c-2$. Can you continue?

> sp $M=(4,2)$, $N=(1,-4)$

Comment: This turns into a equationsystem with 4 unknown? But I cant remember solving equationssystems where we have for example $a^2$ in this early course? Or is there a easier way of solving it?

Comment: @zzz__ Let $b=a^2-3a-2$ and $d=c^2-3c-2$ and $c=2a-7$ in the equation $(d+8)/2=b$. It reduces to a quadratic in $a$

Comment: There should be two solutions, no?

Comment: @user170231 Yeah I think so, but I wasn’t bothered enough to write out the second one!